# Is it possible to write a "double" extension method?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, it is possible to write

```
class A {
  fun B.foo()
}
```

and then e.g. write `with (myA) { myB.foo() }`.

Is it possible to write this as an extension method on `A`, instead?  My use case is writing

```
with (java.math.RoundingMode.CEILING) { 1 / 2 }
```

which I would want to return `1`, the point being that I want to add `operator fun Int.div(Int)` to `RoundingMode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. `operator div` is required to have `Int` as a receiver.

You can't add also `RoundingMode` as receiver, since there can only be single function receiver.

What you can do, though, is use `Pair<RoundingMode, Int>` as a receiver:

```
operator fun Pair<RoundingMode, Int>.div(i: Int): BigDecimal =
        BigDecimal.valueOf(second.toLong()).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(i.toLong()), first)

with(RoundingMode.CEILING) {
    println((this to 1) / 2) // => 1
}
```

Comment: Banged my head on that for half a hour, but this does seem to be the optimal solution.

Comment: My confusion is that it looks like there *is* a way, in Kotlin, to have two receivers: the `class A { fun B.foo() }` example from above, where there are two `this`es in the method `foo`.  But it doesn't look like there's a way for both of those parameters to be extensions to separate types.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Scala has solution to this - implicits. But Kotlin doesn't.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Doesn't my answer below (specially the "context class" part) apply to your problem? It's the way I saw JetBrains do some of the Kotlin magic you see with Coroutines lib and Ktor framework

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, `Int` already has a `div` function, thus, if you decide to write an extension function `div`, you won't be able to apply it, because member functions win over extension functions.

You can write this though:

```
fun RoundingMode.div(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    return if (this == RoundingMode.CEILING) {
        Math.ceil(x.toDouble() / y.toDouble()).toInt()
    } else {
        Math.floor(x.toDouble() / y.toDouble()).toInt()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    with(java.math.RoundingMode.CEILING) {
        println(div(1,2))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for a couple of reasons:

1. There's no "double extension functions" concept in Kotlin
2. You can't override a method with extension functions, and operator `div` is already defined in `Int`

However you can workaround these issues with

1. A context class and an extension lambda (e.g. `block: ContextClass.() -> Unit`)
2. Infix functions (e.g. use `15 div 4` instead of `15 / 4`)

See the example below:

```
class RoundingContext(private val roundingMode: RoundingMode) {
    infix fun Int.div(b: Int): Int {
        val x = this.toBigDecimal()
        val y = b.toBigDecimal()

        val res = x.divide(y, roundingMode)

        return res.toInt()
    }
}

fun <T> using(roundingMode: RoundingMode, block: RoundingContext.() -> T): T {
    return with(RoundingContext(roundingMode)) {
        block()
    }
}

// Test
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    using(RoundingMode.FLOOR) {
        println(5 div 2) // 2
    }
    val x = using(RoundingMode.CEILING) {
        10 div 3
    }
    println(x) // 4
}
```

Hope it helps!